# I don't get all site collections

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, csom

I want to all site collection urls. But when this sorce:

```
New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($Context)
```

I have the next error.

I installed new SKD. But this code is NG.

```
System.Management.Automation.MethodException: "Tenant" のオーバーロードで、引数の数が "1" であるものが見つかりません。
   場所 System.Management.Automation.Adapter.GetBestMethodAndArguments(String methodName, MethodInformation[] methods, PSMethodInvocationConstraints invocationConstraints, Object[] arguments, Object[]& newArguments)
   場所 System.Management.Automation.DotNetAdapter.ConstructorInvokeDotNet(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] arguments)
   場所 Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand.CallConstructor(Type type, ConstructorInfo[] constructors, Object[] args)
```

Comment: $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
$Creds = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Username,$Password) 
$Context.Credentials = $Creds
$Tenant = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($Context) 
$Context.Load($Tenant) 
$Context.ExecuteQuery()

Comment: Could you provide an error message in English? The one in the question looks like Japanese.

Comment: I'm sorry. I translated the error message. "With overload of "Tenant", one with argument number "1" can not be found". But I can get $Context.Load($web) and $Context.Load($web.Webs)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get all site collections from a tenant using PowerShell, the following PowerShell for your reference.

```
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

# Initialize client context
$adminURL = 'https://MyTenant-admin.sharepoint.com/'
$username = 'admin@MyTenant.onmicrosoft.com'
$password = 'MyPassword'
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($adminURL)
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
$credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($username,$securePassword)
$clientContext.Credentials = $credentials

# Enumerate all site collections

$tenant = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantAdministration.Tenant($clientContext)

$props = $tenant.GetSiteProperties(0, $true)
$clientContext.Load($props)
$clientContext.ExecuteQuery()

foreach($sp in $props)
{
       Write-Host 'Title:' $sp.Title
       Write-Host 'Url:' $sp.Url
       Write-Host '-----------------'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use [SPO PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-online/connect-sharepoint-online?view=sharepoint-ps) for this, no need for CSOM.

```
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
Get-SPOSite -Limit All -IncludePersonalSite $true
```